# Traversing HTML using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My sample HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div><span id="temp" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div><span id="temp" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

From the Span tag how do i get the **Table tr**  tag and set its background color ?
   Any easy methods rather than finding parent.parent?

And only the **particular span tag TR** should be changed not all the table TR ?

Thanks

Comment: `$('#temp').parents('tr').css('background-color', 'red');`

Comment: @Chen  Excellent and quick . Modified my question. i need only one TR to change not all the TR. is there a easy way out

Comment: @user2067567: See answer by pXL and comment.

Comment: Use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`, will return only the closest tr.

Comment: Even that affects all TR

Comment: Use parents('tr') - this return only PARENT tr of element, NOT all tr of this table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use `.closest()`

```
$('#temp').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: +1 as `.parents()` causes problems in nested tables, as it matches all `<tr>` parents and will return multiple.  Whereas `.closest()` returns the closest ancestor that matches.

Comment: @pXL how do i make it affect only tat TR and not all TR

Comment: +1. I just read the docs for `.closest()` and `.parents()` and this seems to be faster

Comment: @user2067567, see this demo, when you click on tr, only that tr will change its bg color `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/8NmSA/

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$('#temp').parents('tr').first().css({'background-color': '#fff'});
```

.first() exclude elements in cause of nested tables.

Or [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('#temp').closest('tr').css({'background-color': '#fff'});
```

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery:

```
$("#temp").parents("tr").css('background-color', 'green');
```